# Some of my answers downvoted unnecessarily?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Some of my answers were downvoted unnecessarily and even the moderators decline to look into this saying that: *"flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"* I know that this is not their job to look into. Some examples are: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911188/find-sec-theta-tan-theta/911192#911192), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907336/how-prove-this-inequality-sum-cyc-frac1a3-sum-cyc-frac1abc1-g/911183#911183) [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897415/identity-with-logarithms/897419#897419) .

I know that someone may be serial downvoting, but he has not done many downvotes, so it may not be the case. Also I must say that my these answers are **not** "not useful".

**EDIT:**

There is something useful in my answers. They are downvoted which means they are not useful. But why would someone do that. Maybe he's jealous or dislikes me? CAn something be done? WHy can't I know who downvoted my answer. Why don't they give reason for downvoting my answer?

**EDIT:**
There is some evidence to serial downvoting because my most upvoted answer, which surely wouldn't need a downvote [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888081/trigonometric-simplification-for-limits/888090#888090) was downvoted.

Comment: Now you will have to ask in mathematics-meta-meta, why this question has so many downvotes.

Comment: Downvoting is a privilege, not a matter of necessity.  There may be Answers that elicit my flags *and* downvotes, or only one of those options (or of course, neither).  Does it make sense to complain about "unnecessary" downvotes without also decrying unnecessary upvotes?  I notice your last example has a preponderance of upvotes, in any case.  I urge you simply to ignore the occasional unexplained downvote, or to consider it as [praise by faint damnation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damning_with_faint_praise).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the tooltip for downvoting an answer says "This answer is not useful", people do not always adhere to this guideline. Since voting is anonymous, and voters are not obliged to justify their votes, it is hard to tell the reasons behind a particular vote. I agree that often an explanation would be useful accompanying a downvote so that the author of the post would know how to improve the post; however, this removes the anonymity of the vote, so people often do not comment when they downvote.

Be that as it may, there are scripts that are there to detect serial and targeted voting, and reverse them. If you think that there are such votes that have not been detected, the proper channel is to contact the community managers using the [contact us](https://math.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of most pages on the main and meta sites. The community managers have access to data that the moderators do not.

Comment: see my second edit

Comment: You quoted the tooltip of downvote arrow on questions; on answers it says "This answer is not useful".

Comment: Relevant meta.SE link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212332/what-should-you-do-if-youre-serial-downvoted-it-isnt-automatically-reversed/212339#212339

Answer (score 4):

I personally wouldn't downvote those answers, but I do notice that your answers linked above

1. Have a very high formula-to-explanation ratio;
2. Have significant overlap with other answers to the same question.

I would lean towards these factors being the cause of the downvotes, and not any kind of malicious serial downvoting. Note also that users are under no obligation to explain their downvotes.

Comment: I must tell you that I was the first to post the trigonometry and logarithmic answer, so case of overlap does exist for others' answers they should see before posting, yes I do have a very-very high formula/explanation ratio

Comment: see my second edit